# How to scroll to show search bar under navigation bar like iOS 11 iBook

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, ios11, ibooks

When scrolling up and down, top is fixed like magnetic, but search bar can be shown if drag more. I guess Search bar does not attached to Tableview as 3rd screen shot.

[image]

I record it as video to show scrolling https://youtu.be/3imNlLhlv8Q

How to do it?